# Google analytics: Traffic from Mobiles not tracked

Tags: google-analytics

I have a single page that is being tracked under google analytics. From what I understand, Google analytics has it's own way of tracking mobile data. All I need to do is to filter it in the standard reporting section to be able to know what comes from mobile and what not.

I'm unable to get this data now, it seemed to work earlier.

Question is: Should I be writing any additional script apart from the basic code from GA?

Answer (score 0):

No, you should be able to see Mobile data in at least the following ways:

**new interface**

- Audience => Mobile
- Technology => Browser & OS

**old interface**

- Visitors => Mobile
- Visitors => Browser Capabilities => Browser or Browser & OS

These do not require any changes with the way you track your sites visitors.  Keep in mind, mobile devices that do not support javascript will not be able to report to Google Analytics

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm able to log pageviews from windows and macintosh machines. I just want to know how many pageviews did my page get on iphone, ipad and android mobiles. It's been over 24 hours, and yet no data has been logged.

I use _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'example', 'test', 'test', 1]); to test that a event is logged, and then placed an alert after that to ensure it passes the above step. The alert is displayed on the iphone, but no data is logged against it.

Comment: Sometimes new Events take a few days to show up.  If the GA code works on your full browser, it should work on any phone/device that supports javascript. Is this an event that you only trigger when a mobile browser hits your site?  What iOS version?

Comment: I've not written any specific code for this. All I was doing is to get ga:isMobile to get the number of pageviews on mobile. It worked earlier, it doesn't work now.

Comment: Which interface are you using?  I have never seen an 'isMobile' option.  I have only seen the reports listed in my answer.  Fact remains, you should not be writing any additional script apart from the basic GA code.  They may have changed the way the reports work, however. GA team does this quite often and can differ from one user to the next.

Comment: If you were to use the API you would have seen this. I use the Data feed query explorer to understand the various dimensions and metrics that can be pulled using the API for use in my own reporting tool. 

Google has it's own way of categorizing the pageviews into mobile, just that it hasn't been doing for the last few days. I noticed that it was working during a part of the day today, and isn't now. The UI in GA has changed, so I assume google is doing some kind of a product update!

Comment: If you are using a custom UI wrapped around the GA API, you should state that in your question.  It doesn't say anything about the API.